# RJAGS Multinomial-Dirichlet – Observed node inconsistent with unobserved parents at initialization

Tags: multinomial-distribution, dirichlet-distribution, jags

I am trying to model a simple 2x2 contingency table with a multinomial-Dirichlet model.

A snippet of my data z[i,1:4] look like this:

```
        NFF NFS NSF NSS
  [1,]  12  52  52  61
  [2,]   5   2   2  28
  [3,]   4   8   8 159
  [4,]  27  34  34  60
  [5,]  16  27  27  61
        …
  [207,]
```

Here is my model file:

```
    model
       {
        for (j in 1:K)
          {
           alpha[j] ~ dbeta(a[j],b[j])
            a[j]~ dgamma(0.0001, 0.0001)
            b[j]~ dgamma(0.0001, 0.0001)
           }

            pi ~ ddirch(alpha[1:K])
            total ~ dpois(rate)
            rate ~ dgamma(0.0001, 0.0001)

             for (i in 1:N)
                 { z[i, 1:K] ~ dmulti(pi, total)}
         }
```

My RJAGS calls look like this:

```
    z<-as.matrix(infile)
    K<-ncol(z)
    N<-nrow(z)
    data <- list("z" = z, "N" = N,"K"= K)
    jags.m <- jags.model(file="multinomialmodeloriginal4.jag", data = data,n.chains = 3, n.adapt = 1000)
```

Unfortunately, I run into the following error messages:

```
   Compiling model graph
   Resolving undeclared variables
   Allocating nodes
   Graph Size: 226

   Initializing model
   Deleting model
   Error in jags.model(file = "multinomialmodeloriginal5.jag", data = data,  : 
   Error in node z[1,1:4]
   Observed node inconsistent with unobserved parents at initialization
```

Any suggestions on how to address the initialization error is appreciated. I am a newbie!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any suggestions on how to address the initialization error is appreciated.

A good start would be to actually initialize the parameters :) The problem is that if not initialized correctly, `total` might be a small number, say 5, which is less than `z[1,1:4]`, which means that a `z[1,1:4]` of `12` would be logically impossible, hence the error `Observed node inconsistent with unobserved parents at initialization`.

Just initialize `total` to something safe like `max(z) + 1`:

```
    jags.m <- jags.model(file="multinomialmodeloriginal4.jag", data = data,n.chains = 3, n.adapt = 1000, inits=list(total = max(z) + 1))
```

*Edit:*

Ok, in general you get the error Observed node inconsistent with unobserved parents at initialization for the reasons I specified above. But when I look more closely at your code, I'm not sure that any initialization will work. The problem is that for each row of z you know the length, it can't be anything else than the sum of that row. Therefore it it very strange that you have it as a parameter, as it should just be a variable. try creating a vector length[i] with this property and give it as a variable to JAGS.

If you want to keep `total` in your model there is nothing stopping you from doing that. If you have created the vector `length` that conains the sums of each row in `z` then you can add something like the following statement in you for loop

```
...
  length[i] ~ dpois(total)
}
total ~dunif(0, 999) # Or whatever prior you think is suitable.
```

Comment: I tried changing the initialization as you suggested. I get the same error.

Comment: I tried your approach but I run into the same exact error message. However, if I provide total an initialization that matches the sum(z[1,1:4]), the error message changes to _"Error in node z[**2**,1:4]"_ from   _"Error in node z[**1**,1:4]"_ I got previously.

Comment: Ok, in general you get the error `Observed node inconsistent with unobserved parents at initialization` for the reasons I specified above. But when I look more closely at your code, I'm not sure that any initialization will work. The problem is that for each row of `z` you know the `length`, it can't be anything else than the sum of that row. Therefore it it very strange that you have it as a parameter, as it should just be a variable. try creating a vector `length[i]` with this property and give it as a variable to JAGS.

Comment: Thanks fixing the length solved the initialization problem – I run into an _Slicer stuck at value with infinite density_ error. Fortunately, there is a stack exchange thread for that error with the Multinomial-Dirichlet. I am still interested in modeling my "total" variable. I have an ensemble of contingency tables and want to model both the total number of counts and the probabilities.

Comment: Added more info to the answer.

Comment: The modification from your edit worked very nicely. My infinite density errors also disappeared and my Gelman plots got way better. Thanks a ton!